# Magento 1.8.0.0 Configuration changes won't save

Tags: configuration

I'm attempting to change the numbers of items viewed in the Products per Page on Grid Default Value. I've changed the allow all setting to yes, and changed the products per page to 30 (30 is listed in Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values.)

Once I hit "Save congig" it goes through a short cycle, then resets my changes to the default values.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you have a look in your browser's networking tab do you see any errors on the request?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a validation error in one of the backend models used for one of the fields in the catalog configuration section.
So when you save the config, something crashes and nothing gets saved.
Check the `var/log` folder for errors.
Also Before hitting save, open all the fieldsets in the page.
If I'm right you should see some error message somewhere.